# What is default maximum request length in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to know what is default maximum request length in a .net core application.

I read from few links that the default limit is **4 MB** for asp.net applications and same should apply here.

But on testing i found that even without overriding the default limit i am able to upload files of size around **14 MB** but it fails for files of size around **30 MB**.

I certainly know how to increase this limit but i want to know what is the default limit. Is there any c# code to check? Could not find any related documentation regarding this.

Comment: It depends not only .NET Core but also the web server config which you are using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of ASP.NET Core 6, the default maximum request body size is 30,000,000 bytes, which is approximately 28.6 MB. These are the same defaults if you are running against IIS or Kestrel.

Sources:

[ASP.NET Core docs - Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#kestrel-maximum-request-body-size)

[ASP.NET Core docs - IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#iis)

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for. Did not get this part "When hosting with Kestrel". For IIS hosting also we need to use Kestrel server and iis as proxy, right or is it about hosting in linux and mac case?

Comment: Kestrel itself is a standalone cross-platform web server and therfore runs on linux and mac as well as windows. Under windows you can use the IIS integration by calling `.UseIISIntegration()` in the Startup. This then will use IIS as proxy for your Kestrel backend.

Comment: Ok, We are using IIS integration and application is hosted in widows server via IIS. So, 28.6 MB is the size which i was looking for and my test also shows that at 30 mb it fails, so no max size is not the case. Thanks

Comment: As of .NET core 2.0 it appears the Kestrel max now also defaults to 28.6MB [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxrequestbodysize?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Answer (score 3):

The default maximum filesize is 4MB.

If you want to increase the upload size, you can do it like this:

Using application wise settings - in the configure services method. In this example, upload up to 100 MB file.

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 100000000;
});
```

Comment: What if the upload isn't multipart, i.e. Request.Body as a stream?

Comment: I ran a test on .NET 6.0 and a default request content size is 30MB not 4MB.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your Execution Timeout is short coz aside from maximum lenght you also need to take note that web page only execute on  maximum seconds of time.. in php it is 60 seconds. For asp.net you can modify the web.config add this on httpRunTime

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"
```

where 300 is equivalent to 5 minutes or 300 / 60.

I hope this resolve your issue and happy coding! =)